# Adding a confidence interval line to RDplot in R

Tags: r, rdd, confidence-interval

I am trying to add a dashed confidence intervals lines (upper and lower bound) using the RDplot command and unable to do so. The RDplot allows to only add a CI as a point estimate or a shade.

My attempt so far:

```
# rd estimates 
est1 = rdrobust(y =y1, x = x, c=0, cluster=cluster, covs=covs)

#Figure 2a: RD plot 
rdplot(y=y1, x=x, subset=-est1$bws[1,1]<= x & x <= est1$bws[1,2],
       covs=covs, binselect="esmv", kernel="triangular",
       h=c(est1$bws[1,1], est1$bws[1,2]), p=1, 
       title="", 
       y.label="School records",
       x.label="Margin of Victory") 

# Calculate confidence interval bounds
lower_bound <- est1$ci[1, 1]
upper_bound <- est1$ci[1, 2]

# Add confidence interval band as a dotted line
abline(v = c(lower_bound, upper_bound), lty = "dotted")
```

The last three lines is my attempt to add the CI lines but it does not seem to work.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?